# Are there open-source "rate my X" website tools?

Tags: open-source, web, rating

Not as in "hot or not" type sites, but consumer/community sites like "rate my college professor" or "rate my plumber" etc., sites where people can comment and rank things.

I was just wondering if there's some kind of PHP/MySQL package which has some basics already done.

It's hard to know what to search for.

Oh and by the way, yes, I know to get legal advice about setting up a site like this.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at Drupal - www.drupal.org - and in particular the voting modules.

Comment: Thanks. I hadn't thought of that.